# is it possible to set the java decompiler to very verbose

Tags: java, apk, decompiler

Is it possible to set the java decompiler to return everything it finds during the process? I have a game I have been working on for a little over a year, I am still pretty new to java and have been beating my head against the keyboard and api documentation to produce this game. I come home from a business trip and find that my house has been broken into and my workstation is gone. I still have my keystore because I keep it on a flashdrive for safety. I also keep my project files on a flashdrive, which I did not remove from my workstation before leaving on my trip. I have tried to use every .apk decompiler I can find to recover my source code. They all return some code but of course because of proguard almost all of it is unusable. I have a copy of my signed .apk on my phone for testing purposes and it is debuggable, is there anyway to recover all of my project files from this? Like setting the java decompiler to very verbose, or a different setting that will produce a 1:1 copy of each file reguardless of if the decompiler thinks it is relavent?

Edit:  I have used dj java decompiler, androchef decompiler and the decompiler @ www.decompileandroid.com which is just a script that is run on their server to use the standard tools included in eclipse adt package for developing android applications.

Comment: Seems like proguard is doing its job. In the future you might want to think about offsite backup for your important files. I use an owncloud instance on a cheap webhost.

Comment: This seems like a pretty broad question. *Which* decompiler are you referring to?

Comment: I have edited my post to reflect the additional information.

Answer (score 0):

I used to deobfuscate Java applications for a hobby and have worked on several decompilers, so if you send it to me, I might be able to help.

That being said, there are some things that are simply impossible to fix. You're never going to get back anything that isn't present in the compiled apk because it's impossible to recover information that isn't there. Among other things, this includes comments, original source code formatting, and compile time annotations. The obfuscation step will also strip out class names, variable names, unused methods, etc.

One other thing to try is to see if there's any possible way that a non obfuscated version of apk survived. Did you ever upload your files anywhere else?

Comment: unfortunately no i never loaded it anywhere other than the flash drive, i had toyed with loading the project files to my phone which i will be doing from now on, i just didn't want to use the space as i of course figured my home was safe since this is a unknown project from my daily career. there is an app in the playstore called "Show Java" it seems to have a pretty good success rate from what i see on returning the code, is there anything like this for Windows? I would much rather retype all 400,000 lines of code then start over.

Comment: I am not familiar with Show Java specifically.Most likely it's just frontend to one of the various Java decompilers out there. If the app isn't too badly obfuscated, I'd recommend trying dex2jar + Procyon. If the app does have good obfuscation, then nothing is going to work well out of the box, but I can take a look and see what I can do if you want.